# Angular 2 "Error encountered resolving symbol values statically." running i18n

Tags: angular, error-handling, compiler-errors, internationalization, angular2-aot

I am trying to run the i18n extraction tool for translation of my angular 2 app. 
But when I try to run I get:

```
Failed on type {"filePath":"C:/ng/anbud/src/app/_common/logging-error handler.ts","name":"LoggingErrorHandler"} with error Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could
 not resolve type LoggingErrorHandlerOptions (position 34:53 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol LoggingErrorHandler in C:/ng/anbud/src/app/_common/logging-error-handler.ts
Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve type LoggingErrorHandlerOptions (position 34:53 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol LoggingErrorHandle
r in C:/ng/anbud/src/app/_common/logging-error-handler.ts
    at simplifyInContext (C:\ng\anbud\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\static_reflector.js:469:23)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (C:\ng\anbud\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\static_reflector.js:472:22)
    at StaticReflector.parameters (C:\ng\anbud\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\static_reflector.js:102:47)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata (C:\ng\anbud\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14317:56)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getTypeMetadata (C:\ng\anbud\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14282:28)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (C:\ng\anbud\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14473:42)
    at C:\ng\anbud\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14421:47
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProvidersMetadata (C:\ng\anbud\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14405:21)
    at C:\ng\anbud\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14412:43
Extraction failed

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\js\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "i18n"
npm ERR! node v6.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! beskrivelse@0.1.0 i18n: `ng-xi18n`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

The error is in my custom error handler:

```
// Import the core angular services.
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
// import { forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

// Import the application components and services.
import { ErrorLogService } from './error-log.service';

export interface LoggingErrorHandlerOptions {
  rethrowError: boolean;
  unwrapError: boolean;
}

export var LOGGING_ERROR_HANDLER_OPTIONS: LoggingErrorHandlerOptions = {
  rethrowError: false,
  unwrapError: false
};

@Injectable()
export class LoggingErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  private errorLogService: ErrorLogService;
  private options: LoggingErrorHandlerOptions;

  constructor(
    errorLogService: ErrorLogService,
    @Inject(LOGGING_ERROR_HANDLER_OPTIONS) options: LoggingErrorHandlerOptions <!--- ERROR
  ) {
    this.errorLogService = errorLogService;
    this.options = options;
  }
```

The error handler is based on this article: 
https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3138-creating-a-custom-errorhandler-in-angular-2-rc-6.htm

So if you want to see the code in it's entirety you can see it there.

Anyone know why this error is thrown?

Comment: the same problem for me when using ng2-translate module. May be you are using something similar? If so, try to remove it

Answer (score 2):

just a wild guess here:

change

```
export interface LoggingErrorHandlerOptions
```

to

```
export class LoggingErrorHandlerOptions
```